# why can't I use touch at all?

Tags: bash, grep, touch, echo

I have this script that basically needs to add

```
alias www-owns-assets="sudo chown www-data public/assets -R"
```

to ~/.bash_aliases if this line (or this file) does not exist.

Here is the script:

```sh
ls ~/

LINE='alias www-owns-assets="sudo chown www-data public/assets -R"'

FILE='~/.bash_aliases'

touch $FILE

grep -qsFx -- "$LINE" $FILE || echo "$LINE" >> $FILE
```

The `touch` line throws an error:

```
touch: cannot touch '~/.bash_aliases': No such file or directory
```

even though ls ~/ works fine. What am I doing wrong? (I have tried with and without quotes marks - but perhaps not the right ones.

Comment: This is answered here <https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151865/388654>

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/why-doesnt-the-tilde-expand-inside-double-quotes

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a duplicate (see above links).

Answer (score 1):

The use of `~` is unreliable it may or may not work on scripts and `~` will not expand if it is quoted (single or double). Try using `$HOME` instead.

```
FILE=$HOME/.bash_aliases
```

...Or remove the quotes.

```
FILE=~/.bash_aliases
```

- But like what I've said it is better to use `$HOME`.
- As an aside note avoid using Capital letters on variables that is purely for internal purposes.